# how to programatically mark generated source folder as Generated Sources Root

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlinpoet

I am investigating generating Kotlin code with KotlinPoet

i would like to be able to programatically mark the target directory as "`Generated Sources Root`"

however i cannot see a KotlinPoet option for this.

is it possible to mark my target directory as "`Generated Sources Root`" from my generator code?

or do i have to manually configure this using IntelliJ?

or is it possible to configure this from my groovy gradle build file?

Comment: You could use https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html with code similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219200